# Projections in tensor product of vN algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Can we write any projection in the tensor product vN algebra $M\otimes N$ in terms of limits of projections $p\otimes q$, where $p$ and $q$ are projections in M, N or somewhat relate the projections onto their components!!

Comment: It can't be done for $M$ and $N$ finite dimensional factors (the rank of a pure tensor is the product of the ranks, and the unit ball is compact, ...), so why should we expect it to be true for infinite-dimensional ones?

Comment: Expecting relations on the componenet projections